# Phonegap build default icon vs Cordova cli build default icon

Tags: cordova, icons, phonegap-build

I want to write a config.xml such that it can be used by both phonegap build and phonegap CLI.

For the default icon,

phonegap build requires the icon to be placed under app/www/icon.png, and config.xml declared as

```
<icon src="icon.png" />
```

But in phonegap cli, it seems that it is unable to recognize the path above. And will throw an error while building.

i have also tried

```
<icon src="www/icon.png" />
```

But this does not work in phonegap build. The app icon is displayed on the webpage, but the app downloaded does not have an icon.

Does anyone know what is the best way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Cordova build icon definitions -->
<icon src="www/icon.png" />

<!-- Phonegap build icon definitions -->
<icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" />
<icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="android" />
```

Resolved the issue with the above confix.xml